# Android. Каким запросом в GoogleMap App открыть место по координатам, чтоб высветился адрес?

Tags: android, google-maps, геолокация

Вот этим запросом я открываю приложение гугло карт

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+korOtpr+"(Отсюда)"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Приложение открывается с маркером обозначается место, но нужно еще чтоб показывался адрес этого места. Какой запрос для этого применить?

Comment: вы открывает не гулу карты, вы делаете неявный запрос. Может открыться любое другое приложение работающее с локализацией. От этого будет зависеть ответ.
Вы не можете вывести адрес или вы не можете его получить зная координаты?

Comment: Я хочу чтоб приложение гугло карт показывало адрес по координатам, которые я ему передаю.

Answer (score 3):

Определяем адрес по координатам:

```
    double latitude = 37.7749; // любые данные
    double longitude = -122.4194; // любые данные
```

...

```
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
```

Ставим маркер по нашим координатам и показываем полученный адрес:

```
    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude + ", " + latitude + "?q=" + Uri.encode(address));
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Используем [googlemaps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#intent) здесь есть отличный гайд.

Comment: Да способ хорош) Как раз задал тут свой вопрос, потому что подозреваю что данный способ лимитирован 1000 запросов в день) За гайд спсибо, никак не мог его найти.

Comment: это вариант который пришел в голову, ну я все равно думаю, что придется дописывать куски, к примеру, что если координаты не имеют адрес? или адрес какой-то некорректный, нужно делать заглушки или свой класс который обрабатывает адрес по входным данным. Вот вы ещё говорите, что есть ограничения я не знал, на днях почитаю и вам спасибо за такой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать класс `Geocoder`:

```
Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(myContext);
ArrayList<Address> addresses = gCoder.getFromLocation(123456789, 123456789, 1);
if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
    Toast.makeText(myContext, "country: " + addresses.get(0).getCountryName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Подробнее :[Тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)